# Missing Microsoft XML reference on macOS Sierra 10.12.1, Office Mac 2011 14.6.1

Tags: xml, excel, windows, macos, vba

I am porting an Excel VBA module from Windows to Macintosh.  If I have the terminology right, the module uses a reference called "Microsoft XML, v3.0."  This is marked "MISSING" on the Mac.  Other references are working as expected.  I have poked about a bit on each platform, looking at other references that are working properly.  It seems the five other references that work are associated with files in the Office directory hierarchy on both platforms.

The XML reference has "Location: C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll" on the Windows computer.  On the Mac, Excel appears to be looking in the same directory as the workbook, probably a sensible default in some situations.

Is there any hope for this porting project?

*EDIT: I fixed some terminology above and added the following paragraph below.*

I think I could reverse engineer C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll and re-implement it (or a subset) for macOS, but that seems a big job and not very much hope.

Comment: The Mac will have an equivalent. You'll have to rewrite it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I'm not completely sure what you're saying.

Comment: The MAC will have it's own way of interacting with web servers. You cannot use the Windows way on a Mac.

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure what "the Mac will have an equivalent" meant.  Thanks!

Comment: Searching on `mac xml http` gives this as one result. http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html showing Windows and Mac code.

Comment: It indeed looks like the Microsoft XML Core Services (MSXML)  are a Windows-only affair:  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSXML and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760399(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'm still ignorant about what MSXML contains (and what subset of it our module needs) but I found https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web.  I'll take a closer look later.